# None Type object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

i try to fix it but, i cannot....
please help me, i do not know why it display that error.

```
def sorted_point_list(lst):
    import math
    def distance(point):
        return math.sqrt(point[0]**2 + point[1]**2)
    def max_point(lst):
        def max_distance(lst):
            if lst == []:
                return 0 
            else:
                return max(distance(lst[0]),max_distance(lst[1:]))
        a = max_distance(lst)
        for i in lst:
            if distance(i) == a:
                return i
    def iter_(lst,result):
        if lst == []:          
            return result
        c = max_point(lst)
        return iter_(lst.remove(c),c+result)
    return iter_(lst,[])
```

Comment: Please post the full error message (ie traceback) so we know where to look.

Comment: It's a very common error, it means a function returned `None` instead of a list.

Comment: What list is this function being called with? Any list I give to it (for example, `sorted_point_list([4, 9, 1])` throws a `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` error.

Comment: the list will be like [[1,2],[3,4],[5,5]]...thanks

Comment: this code looks like lisp not idiomatic python

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when you are getting `None` as a return value of something where you assume you'll be getting some other value (a list in this case).

Your `max_point()` function does not return a value in all cases. Therefore it returns `None` in those cases. This is a possible source of the error message you're getting.

Also, you're treating the `remove()` method of lists as though it returns a list. It does not; it modifies the list in place but returns `None`. This is also a possible source of the error.

As an aside, nesting functions the way you have is generally not a good idea. Inner functions will be redefined each time the outer function is called, which can be a significant performance penalty, especially if the outer function is called in a loop. (Similarly for the `import`, which will be executed each time you call `sorted_point_list()`.)

Comment: I think the max_point() is wrong as well, then I try the max_point()part individually and it can give me the right return as a point.

Answer (score 1):

problem seems to be this `lst.remove(c)`, `remove()`  changes the list in place and returns `None`. You're assuming it to be a list here.

Inside `max_distance()` you're passing `lst[0]` to `distance()`, and for `None` it'll raise the error `None Type object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: the max_distance() could return a value where i test it individually.

Comment: @user1598686 test it with `iter_()`.